# Schema version update for new models

Tags: ios, swift, realm

It's a bit unclear to me, if the schema version needs to be updated when I am adding a completely new model.

According to the [migration doc](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations) it is clear that Realm is doing auto-migrations for added/removed properties. However, is it considered a database migration when I am adding or removing a model?

Comment: Yes, its one type of migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the schema version does not need to be bumped when adding an entirely new type. Only changes to existing types do, as that's a potentially destructive operation.

Comment: Does a removal of a complete model require a bump? Maybe the documentation for migration should be updated to state when a version bump is needed. Right now I just add them for everything related to the database cause I'm never sure if it's needed or not.